# Rails call Action from Partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

just started with rails. i have quick question. have a customer view which includes a partial project view. the partial includes some crud actions. when i click on them the customer crud are executed. 
appreciate some help.
thanks,
ed

Comment: can you post an example of the crud link_to helpers?

Comment: I failed to see what is the real question?